# ListActivity Item with remote image

Tags: android, listactivity

I have a ListActivity that should display quite a lot of items and where each list item should contain a text and and an image. The images are gotten from a remote server. How can I display the remote image on the list item. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the images into memory or a local cache using `HttpURLConnection` or similar then use `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` to convert the downloaded images into bitmaps and assign them to ImageViews using `setImageDrawable` to display them.